# Restructuring data; Generate an overview of routelocations based on routepoints

Tags: sql, postgresql

Looking for help with an sql statement restructuring my data. I have a dataset which has a lot of points of a lot of routes. Each point has a routeid, time and a location.

Like this:

```
routeid, time, location 
1, 2017-04-06 14:15:33, Netherlands
1, 2017-04-06 14:15:35, Netherlands
1, 2017-04-06 14:15:38, Netherlands
1, 2017-04-06 14:15:42, Netherlands
1, 2017-04-06 14:15:48, Belgium
1, 2017-04-06 14:15:52, Belgium
1, 2017-04-06 14:15:56, Belgium
2, 2017-04-06 14:15:44, Netherlands
2, 2017-04-06 14:15:52, Netherlands
2, 2017-04-06 14:15:56, Netherlands
2, 2017-04-06 14:16:00, Germany
2, 2017-04-06 14:16:04, Germany
```

Now I am trying to make an overview of which locations each route has passed from what time till what time. So with above data:

```
routeid, location1, starttime, endtime, location2, starttime, endtime
1, Netherlands, 2017-04-06 14:15:33, 2017-04-06 14:15:42, Belgium, 2017-04-06 14:15:48, 2017-04-06 14:15:56
2, Netherlands, 2017-04-06 14:15:44, 2017-04-06 14:15:56, Germany, 2017-04-06 14:16:00, 2017-04-06 14:16:04
```

This is a sample with the same structure. The data itself has a lot more points and locations, so it could become a table with a lot of columns. I would like to generate this table with SQL code. But I am having some problems starting my script. It seems like I need to loop through the data, yet I am using SQL. What is the approach I should follow? Take the data out and use Python or is there some way of doing it in SQL which is easy to learn with pssql?

Comment: Ordinarily something like this would be a `PIVOT` operation in SQL, but the issue with that is that you would need to know the number of columns in advance (and it looks like you won't necessarily know that - it will depend on the number of locations). You *can* get all the locations as rows, and then use another tool (e.g. python) to do the pivoting.

Comment: Working on generating the amount of locations per route now. So then I would be able to predict the columns I need and ill try to fill it in with PIVOT. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The only issue with that is that you would need a separate query for each number of locations. However, it would be possible to build the query as a text string and then execute it (**dynamic SQL**)

Comment: Just to help people get this solved, I've created a SQL fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8abf8/4 I'll come back to this, as I think we can do something close with a `GROUP BY`.